# How to search a list of strings in a data frame column and return the matching string as an adjacent column

Tags: python, pandas

##### What I have

I have a column 'Student' with students name and their personalities.
I have a list named as 'qualities' that consisits of qualities that is required for filtering purpose.

###### What I want

I want a column next to to the 'Student' that returns the matching string from the list.

###### What I have

```
import pandas as pd

Personality = {'Student':["Aysha is clever", "Ben is stronger", "Cathy is clever and strong", "Dany is intelligent", "Ella is naughty", "Fred is quieter"]}
index_labels=['1','2','3','4','5','6']
df = pd.DataFrame(Personality,index=index_labels)

qualities = ['calm', 'clever', 'quiet', 'bold', 'strong', 'cute']
```

###### What I want

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnK0N.png)

Comment: And why not have a singe additional column that would contain a list of matched words? Adding an arbitrary column for each match does not seem reasonable.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74785642/edit) (it covers program input and output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the original DataFrame:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, qualities))

out = df.join(df['Student'].str.extractall(f'({pattern})')[0].unstack())
```

Output:

```
                      Student       0       1
1             Aysha is clever  clever     NaN
2             Ben is stronger  strong     NaN
3  Cathy is clever and strong  clever  strong
4         Dany is intelligent     NaN     NaN
5             Ella is naughty     NaN     NaN
6             Fred is quieter   quiet     NaN
```

Comment: Mozway I've a doubt after split if i want to access my elements normally we use index like so `str.split()[1]` gives 1st elemnt in list...How do I mention range/mention multiple indexes at a time something like `[1][3][4]` ...It deson't work says wrong syntax

Comment: @Bhargav not sure I follow you, do you want `operator.itemgetter(1, 3, 4)('A B C D E'.split())`?

Comment: See my answer posted above there I'm using `new = df["ex"].str.split(pat = ",", expand=True)[1]` which gives me  first elemnt in list after split...if I want filter like hand-picked indexes at a time how can I do it...Like If i want 1st, 4th, 7th indexes how can i mention after split...`[1][4][7] `?

Comment: I wonder how to make it immune case sensitive @mozway

Comment: @user16490995 do you mean case **in**sensitive? You can use `f'(?i)({pattern})'` as pattern

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.findall](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and then split by `,`

```
df['ex'] = df['Student'].str.findall('|'.join(qualities)).apply(set).str.join(', ')

new = df["ex"].str.split(pat = ",", expand=True)[1]
df =pd.concat([df, new], axis = 1)
df = df.fillna('')
print(df)
```

Gives #

```
                      Student              ex        1
1             Aysha is clever          clever
2             Ben is stronger          strong
3  Cathy is clever and strong  clever, strong   strong
4         Dany is intelligent
5             Ella is naughty
6             Fred is quieter           quiet
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Gives #"*?